# Algorithm to detect monthly semimonthly biweekly dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, validation, data-analysis

Using PostgreSQL (11+), Ruby (2.6+) and Rails (5.2+)

I have a series of dates representing payroll dates, e.g.

```
2000-06-30
2000-06-15
2000-05-30
2000-05-15
2000-04-28
2000-04-14
2000-02-15
2000-01-28
2000-01-14
```

Caveats:

- A series may be incomplete, with gaps covering one or more payroll dates.
- The employing organization sets their own schedule, so, for example, semi-monthly might be the 15th and 30th or 1st and 16th or some other combination.
- The last date (or possibly two) might be "wrong" by being out of sync with the earlier payrolls if an employee's final paycheck was cut in the wrong payroll.
- The employee may have received payments from multiple differently-scheduled payrolls during the series, possibly overlapping.

What algorithm or approach can I apply to detect, with reasonable confidence, the payroll frequency applicable as of the end of the series?

**Edit:**

The intended output is one of these four symbols:

- :monthly
- :semimonthly
- :biweekly
- :weekly

(Payroll frequencies other than these four can be ignored in this specific situation, but might be helpful in crafting a general-purpose solution.)

Comment: What do you mean payroll frequency, what exactly do you need to calculate?

Comment: It might be helpful if you provide an example of what output data you would want a method to return given certain input data.  You have not made it very clear what you're end goal is. What does "the payroll frequency applicable" even mean?  It sounds to me like you need to break your problem into smaller pieces to solve this.

Comment: What are we to make of "missing dates", "gaps"? If there were three dates, "2000-06-30", "2000-07-30" and "2000-08-30" and the dates "2000-07-15" and "2000-08-15" were "missing", how could we conclude that payday was twice monthly? If in this example we also had dates "2000-09-15" and "2000-09-30", are we to reason that the presence of "2000-09-15" indicates that there were mid-month paydays in previous months that are missing? To make this a Ruby problem you need to give us the rules.

Comment: Thank you for these comments. Joel and @lacostenycoder, I have added expected output examples. The gaps you describe, Cary, are definitely part of my puzzlement. That's why I'm asking for "a reasonable level of confidence", not for clairvoyance into the intentions of some past payroll clerk.

This is a general-purpose programming question, specifying Ruby only as a *lingua franca*.

Comment: What’s the difference between biweekly (is that every two weeks? Us brits use “fortnightly” which sounds old fashioned but avoids ambiguity where biweekly can also meen twice per week) and semimonthly?

Comment: Thanks, Tom. In my situation, bi-weekly is indeed fortnightly. You get 26 paychecks each year. With semi-monthly, you get 24 paychecks per year.

Comment: What you didn't supply was a passing test case.  Given this input, I expect this output. Using [Test Driven Development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) can be helpful in solving problems like this.

Comment: One of the issues, @lacostenycoder, is that with the above-listed complexities, I'm at risk of making the example test cases too simple, or wrong. I'm hoping that, as our community weighs-in on this question, we'll see some novel approaches I haven't imagined yet that shine a light on obscure patterns in the data, render more accuracy, and give higher confidence in the complex cases.

Comment: @DanielAshton having edge cases is common. You can still write tests for the non-edge cases right?

Comment: Absolutely! I'm an advocate for TDD, and I appreciate your comments here, @lacostenycoder. I omitted tests in the question above because I'm hoping for some out-of-the box thinking that would be distracted, perhaps, by either simplistic base test cases, or by complex edge cases.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity around frequencies. Another key part of how to best design this is about how many data points you will have. With 10yr or salary payments you can pretty easily have high confidence. But do you want to get some results very few; maybe 3 payments only? With very low number of data points you might want an algo which can be rerun as each additional datapoint is received - producing ever higher confidence results as the data set grows.

Answer (score 2):

Go through the array and calculate the difference between the current and next item in the list (eg 2000-06-30 - 2000-06-15 = 15) until you have a list of “number of days between payrolls” (eg [15, 15, 15, 17 ...])

Then, use the mode of that list to find the most common distance between payrolls (given the above example the mode is 15). You’ll be tempted to find the mean/average but mode is better suited to ignoring those “wrong” dates.

Shout if you need help implementing either of these steps in ruby but you should find some SO answers already out there to get you started.

Finally, create a “test” list of dates - one where you manually know the answer you want. Play with that until your algorithm gives you that answer.

Comment: Sounds like you recommend using Test Driven Development, which is surely a good idea.